# What is the best way to repair the bootloader of Windows10 tech preview without resetting the installation?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, windows-10-preview

I installed Windows10 tech preview and lot's of software (visual studio, steam acount and all my games, chrome, firefox, 7zip). When I add my Windows8 disk and boot, the win8 disk autocheck change the start of the Windows10, but i still have access to the recovery boot.

If i reset Windows10, I loose all the installed apps. What is the best way to restore the normal Windows 10 boot?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I change the default boot operations on windows 8 (so it only check the win8 os disk), change some bios settings, did a checkdisk from a cmd line (run by administrator) and had access to the windows 10 install.